# Get changes from previous commit Archanist

Tags: git, arcanist

I used to use `git push` etc and then now I want to create a differential using `arc` (Archanist).

The problem is I want to show all the commits from a very old commit (30 commits behind). Is this possible to do?

So for example, I would like to show the change from `Commit: HEAD - 30 commits` until `HEAD` which is now.

Thanks

Comment: `git log -30` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create new arc diff from last **30 commits**,
you can try to run:

```
arc diff HEAD~30 --preview
```

Once you are happy with it just create diff from it in UI, or you can directly create diff with

```
arc diff HEAD~30
```